# TFS Checkin successful event on client-side

Tags: tfs, checkin

I have extended my Visual Studio TeamExplorer-PendingChanges-Page with a Checkbox, that you need to check, before you can Checkin any changes.
For this I have written a Checkin-Policy and it works.

But I have a Problem, that the Checkbox remains checked, after I have checked in a changeset.
I want to uncheck the Checkbox, if the checkin was successful.

How can I get the CheckinNotification on client-side ?

All I can find is the server-side.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Why is it necessary to uncheck this item after checkin? What is it used for? As far as I know, there is no CheckinNotification on the client side, because VS does a RFC and gets back an exit code / error message. What you could do is to subscribe the CheckinEvent and make a SOAP call to a selfcreated webservice, that unchecks to checkbox. But it makes no sense at the moment to uncheck it, because it is like referencing a work item and after checkin remove the reference.

Comment: Basically the uncheck should work like the comments. As soon as the comments get cleared, when checking in, the Checkbox should also be unchecked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AfterWorkItemsUpdated event from VersionControlServer is raised when the checkin is done.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.afterworkitemsupdated.aspx

Comment: I'll try this out as soon as i can. Thank you!